# Как вывести ссылки и заголовки соседних страниц WP?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть шаблонная страница, по этой шаблонной странице сделал много страниц одного уровня(у них одна общая родительская страница), и все ссылки и названия страниц должны выводиться на каждой странице (т.е. я вставил один блок в шаблон и он сейчас на каждой странице), и в WP я их могу еще добавить. На страницу мне нужно вывести их заголовки и ссылки (в ручную не получится писать, так как их может стать меньше или больше и постоянно заходить в код и исправлять, не подойдет), и если я захожу на одну из этих страниц, то эта страница должна убираться из блока. Искал в интернете как это можно сделать, но ничего не нашел про соседние страницы:( буду рад любой помощи.
Дальше следует тот самый блок со страницами.

```html
<div class="service__directions__content">
  <a href="/" class="service__directions__link"><h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">Что-нибудь</h4></a>
  <a href="/" class="service__directions__link"><h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">Нагрузочное тестирование сайтов</h4></a>
  <a href="/" class="service__directions__link"><h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">Тестирование производительности сайта</h4></a>
  <a href="/" class="service__directions__link"><h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">Проверка сайта на вирусы</h4></a>
  <a href="/" class="service__directions__link"><h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">Тестирование интерфейса</h4></a>
  <a href="/" class="service__directions__link"><h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">Тестирование безопасности сайта</h4></a>
  <a href="/" class="service__directions__link"><h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">Оптимизация скорости загрузки сайта</h4></a>
</div>
```

Вот такой блок на каждой странице [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе, допустим на "дизайн социальных сетей", эта строка должна пропадать, а при переходе на другую страницу, допустим "дизайн мобильной версии", то строка "дизайн социальных сетей" снова появляется, а "дизайн мобильной версии" пропадает.
А при добавлении страницы на WP в этот список автоматически заносится заголовок страницы и ссылка на нее

Comment: Где вывести, где "убираться"? Исправь вопрос, внятно описать что и где делаешь/надо сделать.

Comment: Изменил, надеюсь стало понятнее.

Comment: Извините, но хочется Ваш пост просто в Google Translate закинуть, потому что вроде по-русски, а вроде и не поймешь ничего. "Соседние" можно получить используя [get_adjacent_post()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_adjacent_post), но смотря на то что в примере блока Вы выводите список из определенного количества страниц, то наверное Вам нужно получить список дочерних страниц от Вашей родительской, исключая текущую, так?

Comment: Почти. Вот допустим я нахожусь на странице "Нагрузочное тестирование сайтов", то этот блок все равно есть на странице, только без пункта "Нагрузочное тестирование сайтов". Все эти страницы одного уровня и у них нет дочерних страниц, но есть один общий родитель

Comment: @Simon да, именно это ему и надо. Напишите ответ с примером кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [WP_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query) для того чтобы получить список дочерних страниц от родительской страницы текущей. Все что нужно, это получить ID родительской страницы, передать его в аргументы и исключить из выборки текущую страницу.

```
<?php
global $post;

$args = [
    'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post__not_in'   => [$post->ID]
];

$childrens = new WP_Query($args);

if ($childrens->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="service__directions__content">
        <?php while($childrens->have_posts()) : $childrens->the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="service__directions__link"><?php the_title('<h4 class="h4 service__directions__text__menu">', '</h4>'); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Так же есть вариант с использованием [get_children()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_children)

```
<?php
global $post;

$args = [
    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'exclude'     => $post->ID
];

$childrens = get_children($args);

if ($childrens) : ?>
    <div class="service__directions__content">
        <?php foreach ($childrens as $children) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($children->ID) ); ?>" class="service__directions__link"><?php echo esc_html($children->post_title); ?></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```